# Update array value vs object value

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, object

How do you update the `sku` value within an array as in example "B". Should I go with A over B?

### Option A - Object

#### Scheme

```
"data" : {
    "products" : {
        235099432:{
            "product_id" : 101242538,
            "sku" : "",
            "variant_id" : 235099432
        },
    ]
}
```

#### Update

```
db.col.update({
    "data.products.235099432.variant_id": 235099432
}, {
    $set: {
        "data.products.235099432.sku": "ITM-RED-212"
    }
});
```

### Option B - Array

#### Scheme

```
"data" : {
    "products" : [
        {
            "product_id" : 101242538,
            "sku" : "",
            "variant_id" : 235099432
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$` position operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) to identify the `products` array element to update that matches your filter:

```
db.col.update({
    "data.products.variant_id": 235099432
}, {
    $set: {
        "data.products.$.sku": "ITM-RED-212"
    }
});
```

My vote would be option B; the use of dynamic keys in option A can get very messy.